# Plotting numpy arrays staggered with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Just recently started using matplotlib, so please bear with me.

I have a bunch of numpy arrays (1D) that I want to plot onto the same subgraph. However instead of all on top of each other I want to plot them staggered, say, array #1 starting at x coordinate 0, array #2 starting at x coordinate 5, array #3 starting at x coordinate 10 and so on.

Is there any clever way of doing this? I guess I could simply put an appropriate amount of NaN entries at the start of the arrays first, but I'm pretty sure that this wouldn't be very elegant.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing currently, but since the `plot(x,y)` function would expect x coordinates anyways, just add the appropriate numbers, `plot(x1+5, y1)`,  `plot(x2+10, y2)` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check my code right now, but I use something along the lines of plot(y) and it automatically plots the content of y to their respective indexes. However, it could be a pretty easy fix to do it your way, that's right. Thanks!